# Smart lock not present in Security Settings

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, 6.0-marshmallow, 7.0-nougat, smart-lock

My device is listed to support `Smart Lock`, which bypasses the lock screen security when in a trusted environment. A saved location, bluetooth device, trusted face or voice is required to use this feature.

The location of the `Smart Lock` is normally in *Settings → Security → Smart Lock* , but it isn't present.

**Is there a setting which disables Smart Lock? and how can it be re-enabled?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smart Lock can be *re-enabled* by activating it in

> Settings **→** Security **→** Trust agents **→** Smart Lock (Google)

[image]  [image]